# Dealing with linked lists in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

A simple array may be rendered in Vue like this:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']"
        v-text="item" />
</ul>
```

Is there a simple way to achieve the same result using a "linked list" like the following, without having to nest elements or impact performance (e.g. by converting the list to an array)?

```
{
    title: 'Item 1',
    next: {
        title: 'Item 2',
        next: {
            title: 'Item 3',
            next: null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you either need to flatten your data or have multiple loops.

Comment: What's the concern with performance? Is your data VERY large? If so, you could just render X amount of items at a time.

Comment: Have you tried ES6 iterators? https://medium.com/dailyjs/es6-iterators-and-generators-by-example-d728bfa00c3a - you can use them with `for ( .. of .. )` loop.

Comment: Just add a method or computed property that uses something like `t = ({ title, next }) => next ? [title].concat(t(next)) : [title]` and use that in `v-for`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

Transform you data into an iterable (for this case in an array), by using `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` iterate into your Object to create the new array to display.

Comment: What does flatten have to do with this?

Comment: in order to display your data and not to make a significant impact in the client side,  (by avoid nested v-for directives). Flatten will help you to... well... flat your object (set all key, values in a single object, e.g. `[{title: 'title1', title2: 'title2'}]` so you can create and array of that flatten objects.

Comment: `_flatten` works on arrays. If you can convert that object to an array why would you use lodash?

Comment: i've edited my answer, cause i think, it contain nested arrays. So with Iterate through the object and create a new array with flatten object should work.

Answer (score 0):

As @destoryer suggested, you can create a `computed` property that will call a another function for transforming your linked lists into an array.

```
computed: {
  lists() {
    // assuming that linkedLists is in your data property

    // declared under `methods` in this example
    return this.flattenLists(this.linkedLists); 
  }
},
methods: {
  flattenLists({ title, next }) {
    return next ? [title].concat(this.flattenLists(next)) : [title];
  }
}
```

> `flattenLists` is a recursive function wherein if `next` is an object, it will call itself with `next` as param and concatenate the result to the current array.
>
> In this example, it's under `methods` but it would be better to put it
>   as a helper/util  especially if you want to reuse it
>   in other components.

You can then use it in your `v-for` as such.

```
<ul v-for="(item, index) in lists" :key="index">
  <li>{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The OP prefers to do it `...without having to nest elements or impact performance (e.g. by converting the list to an array)`.

Comment: @jom Then either this or he'll do multiple for loops which also falls as nesting elements which means it will not solve his/her issue as well.